# Sitecore - multiple items of the same type on a web page

Tags: sitecore

Suppose my site has many pages and most pages have 1 or more instances of a simple visual element that has a title, description and a thumbnail. The number of these element on pages is variable. How should I build my data template?

Ideally, I’d like to make a separate data template for this element because its data fields may change in the near future.  I’d like to use this template as a base template for my pages but that only gives me one instance of the data section to work with.

Another requirement is that these elements are not grouped together on a page in a logical manner; they could appear anywhere on the page and Page Editors should be able to freely insert and delete them.

My experience with SiteCore to date is that the web pages are based on rigid data templates so building fluid pages is not what is handled easily. May be I’m missing something as I’m pretty new to the product.

Comment: You can make a new template and let your base page template inherit this. If you have some info that is common to all pages, you should make a standard value to the template. Then you can change the standard values, and all inherited templates has the values changed also.

Comment: thank you for the reply. I understand you answer however it's not what I asked. another example of what i'm doing... suppose i have a car data template with a make/model/image and I want to place 1 or more cars on any given page in any order, above or below other elements of the page. How to I build may page template; I can't simply inherit from the car template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible by creating a sublayout which is just a regular .NET UserControl and create a unique "datasource" template to populate the data for the control. For example, you could create a simple Callout sublayout that requires a Callout DataSource item which has the necessary fields to render.

I've written a blog post about this: [Using the DataSource Field with Sitecore Sublayouts](http://firebreaksice.com/using-the-datasource-field-with-sitecore-sublayouts/)

Comment: Mark: (for sitecore 8.0)Does the template change for the sublayout affect multiple items that were created before the template change or do i need to manually change the template of all those items through configure tab?!

Answer (score 0):

If we use the analogy of a car template with:

1. make
2. model
3. image

as data, then you can have an root item called "car list" in you sitecore tree. After that you can make as many cars as you what.
If you want to add some cars to a certain page then, on the template that you created the page from, you can add a [sitecore treelist](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/XSL/Accessing%20Field%20Values/Treelist.aspx) to the template and make the source of that point to you car list. Now you can reference the choosen cars on a specific page. You can then make a module that can extract the treelist items and show them on your page. This is quite easy because the treelist item is just like any other item.
The good thing about this is you can have standard values put on the car, and when they change, the values changes on all cars on all pages.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a seperate data template for the content block element (title+description+visual).

Then underneath your page item, make a folder (eg. content blocks) that contains the content elements.

When rendering your page you simply load the items from the content blocks folder and render them on the page (by using a repeater, for example).

This way you can control which content blocks appear by just adding/removing them from the folder, you can sort them and you are free to add new fields to them at any point.

If they are not logically placed in a group, you can add a field to the content block that specifies where it should be displayed on the page.